# Sibling itemControllers

Tags: ember.js

I have code similar to this in my template:

`{{#each items itemController="item"}}`

Is there any way to get references to the sibling `itemController`s inside of an instance of one of the `itemController`s?

Comment: I do not think, that this is possible. What's your usecase for it?

Comment: I'm storing the isEditing state in the `itemController`, but I want to only allow one item to be edited at a time. I was thinking I would get the sibling `itemController`s loop thru them and set isEditing to false.

Comment: I would instead have the main controller handle keeping track of which controller is in editing mode, caching the current editing controller in a `currentlyEditing` property and manually handling turning `isEditing` off on the former itemController and on on the incoming itemController.

Answer (score 0):

I'm deleting this answer because in retrospect, while it's technically correct it isn't usefully correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the information about child that has got particular state in parent controller. See an example

```
App.Child = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEdited: false,

    actions: {
        toggleEditingMode: function() {
            old = this.get('parentController.currentlyEditing');

            if(typeof old !== "undefined" && old != this) {
                old.set('isEdited', false);
            }

            this.set('parentController.currentlyEditing', this);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Item controllers are going away pretty soon (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15) and search for `itemController`). What I would suggest you do instead for your use-case is create a component as follows:

```
App.XItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['item'],

  actions: {
    startEdit: function(){
      this.set('beingEdited', true);
      this.set('disallowEdits', true);
    },
    finishEdit: function(){
      this.set('beingEdited', false);
      this.set('disallowEdits', false);
    }
  }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/x-item">
  {{ item }} 
  <button {{ action "startEdit" }} {{ bind-attr   
    disabled=disallowEdits}}>Edit</button>
  {{#if beingEdited}}
    <button {{ action "finishEdit" }}>Save</button>
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

`disallowEdits` is a property that component will share with all the other components (through the controller of the template where the components were created) and `beingEdited` is a local component property not being shared with anyone.

You can then use the component inside a template as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{x-item item=item disallowEdits=disallowEdits }}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Full working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/niceh/3/edit?html,js,output)